# List out the standard and custom objects list without writing code?

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects

I want to prepare a list of standard and custom objects in my salesforce production org. This is for documentation and future reference purpose.

I used Salesforce Optimizer Tool, its really useful but doesn't give me a list of objects. I found that writing apex code is one way to get this.

Is there any way that an admin can get the list of standard and custom objects like using workbench or any such tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the information from workbench.Goto workbench rest explorer tab and run the below query using a get method.

```
/services/data/v45.0/sobjects
```

Documentation [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_describeGlobal.htm)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to find out which custom objects are never used?

Comment: @Techie, if you goto your org and in setup search for storage it shows record count for all objects sorted by highest to lowest